# Rails and Paperclip: Unable to upload images using Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront, paperclip

I have an old Rails application that uses Paperclip to interact with AWS.  I am migrating over to Cloudfront due to TLS compatibility issues, but am running into issues uploading the photos.  I can fetch them just fine, and have ensured that fetching them uses the Cloudfront URL.

Here's my configuration in my model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "images/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
    :url => ':s3_alias_url',
    :s3_host_alias => 'XXX.cloudfront.net',
    :styles => {
      :large => {:geometry => "3500x3500>", :processors => [:cropper]},
      :medium => {:geometry => "512x512>", :processors => [:cropper]},
      :thumb => {:geometry => "160x160>", :processors => [:cropper]}    }
```

However, when I try to upload a photo I receive an error, and from the error it looks like it isn't trying to use the Cloudfront URL:

```
Processing Admin::ImagesController#create (for 24.154.30.187 at 2023-11-03 01:39:51) [POST]
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"admin/images", "commit"=>"Upload Images", "property_id"=>"15948", "action"=>"create", "image"=>{"image"=>[#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20231103-1151-c5g19p-0>, #<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20231103-1151-y1vfa4-0>], "caption"=>""}}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving images/images/467324/thumb.jpg
New RightAws::S3Interface using shared connections mode
Opening new HTTPS connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443
##### RightAws::S3Interface returned an error: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidTlsVersion</Code><Message>Amazon S3 will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. Please update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb. For further assistance, contact AWS suppo$
##### RightAws::S3Interface request: https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/ ####
Closing HTTPS connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443, reason: 'RightAws::AWSErrorHandler: code: 403: 'Forbidden''

RightAws::AwsError (InvalidTlsVersion: Amazon S3 will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. Please update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb. For further assistance, contact AWS support.):
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/awsbase/right_awsbase.rb:562:in `request_info_impl'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3_interface.rb:203:in `request_info'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3_interface.rb:240:in `create_bucket'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3.rb:103:in `bucket'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:163:in `s3_bucket'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:199:in `flush_writes'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:195:in `each'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:195:in `flush_writes'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:141:in `save'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:331:in `send'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:331:in `save_attached_files'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:324:in `each_attachment'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:323:in `each'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:323:in `each_attachment'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:330:in `save_attached_files'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
  activesupport (2.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/base.rb:2539:in `save_without_validation'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:1009:in `save_without_dirty'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (2.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
  app/controllers/admin/images_controller.rb:28:in `create'
  app/controllers/admin/images_controller.rb:26:in `each'
  app/controllers/admin/images_controller.rb:26:in `create'
```

When I view previously uploaded photos though, it shows the correct url: https://XXX.cloudfront.net/images/images/XXX/thumb.jpg?2023?1698977169

What am I missing?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I'm fully aware of this.  There's an update in progress that isn't completed yet.  Have any helpful information?

Comment: Seems like TLS1.2 was added in Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Again, fully aware of that.  You can get around that by uploading to S3 through Cloudfront.  That is the sole task I'm trying to accomplish in this question.

Comment: I doubt you can. TSL 1.0 and 1.1 were deprecated in 2021 and should not be supported anywhere at this point. It's not ever supported in [Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-soon-to-be-disabled-in-windows/ba-p/3887947) products anymore. What you could do is set up some kind of a proxy (Nginx would be a good choice) to accept TLS 1.0 requests on one side and forward them to AWS. Or a background job in a newer version of ruby that checks a specific dir and uploads all files to S3 periodically.

Comment: Not trying to be smirk, but at this point no public web server should be accepting TLS 1.1 connections, so most likely you need to set up your own.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-access-old-tls
This is a valid work around suggested by Amazon.  No it's not a permanent fix, but it is what we need to do today in order to keep operating the business while we get the actually full upgrade done.  AWS accepts TLS 1.1 through Cloudfront

Comment: @engineersmnky I have worked with AWS Support that have made it VERY clear that any request to Cloudfront will support the old versions of TLS.  Paperclip is making the POST request to the bucket URL and not the Cloudfront URL.  That is what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: So looking through the source your issue is here: https://github.com/flexera-public/right_aws/blob/v3.0.4/lib/awsbase/right_awsbase.rb#L387. While it took a lot of tracking and I am not 100% sure I figured it out can you try and pass the following option `:s3_headers => {:server => WHATEVER_SERVER_YOU_NEED_TO_HIT}`

Comment: @engineersmnky So I have tried that and it still tries to put the bucket name in front, but if I remove the bucket name it thinks the bucket doesn't exist and tries to create it.  I've been poking through the source too and am now looking into `RightAws::AcfInterface` to see if maybe that's what it should use instead of the S3 interface

Comment: @SaraFuerst given this is a temporary situation for you maybe just override that method to form the url appropriately and see if that works as a patch?

Comment: @engineersmnky That's the rough idea of what I'm trying. I've figured out it seems to try to list all the items in the bucket (using the bucket notation) before it tries uploading the items, and that's what's causing the TLS error.  I don't think that's strictly necessary so I'm working on getting around that and doing the upload directly

Answer (score 0):

The first issue was that the version of Paperclip I was stuck with uses the `right_aws` gem, rather than the AWS SDK directly.  Because of this, the parameters were not being set to send the responses to the Cloudfront URL.  I had to manually set the server in the `request` object to the Cloudfront URL.

Second, when listing objects or the buckets from S3 through Cloudfront, the information it was looking for was not being returned.  I had to remove any checks to see if the objects I was trying to delete or upload already existed.  After this, I was successfully able to upload to S3 using TLS 1.1!